# new entity with entity metadata wraper and multiple collection fields, how set a first new collection field ?

Tags: entities

I have one custom content. It contains a multiple collection field. 
If I create a new entity (via entity_metadata_wraper), how can I set a new multiple collection field ?

by example :

```
$new_entity = entity_create('node', array('type'=>'custom content');
$new_entity_w = entity_metadata_wrapper('node',$new_entity);
...
$new_entity_w->a_new_multiple_collection_field[0]->some_field->set('...'); //(1) doesn't work
//$new_entity_w->a_new_multiple_collection_field[]->some_field->set('...'); //(2)doesn't work
```

Error for (1) : 
Unable to set the data property some_field as the parent data structure is not set

Error for (2) : 
PHP Fatal error : Cannot use [] for reading in /var/...

I didn't find...thank you for some help !

Comment: Have you tried: $new_entity_w->a_new_multiple_collection_field[0]->some_field[0]->set('...');

Comment: Pardon, I didn't notice the question is about a collection field.

Comment: Thanks for replying ! $new_entity_w->a_new_multiple_collection_field[0]->some_field[0]->set('...'); 
I get an error : PHP Fatal error: Cannot use object of the EnriryValueWrapper as array in /var/...